# H2 Database Server to serve TCP clients from connection pool

Tags: tcp, connection, h2

I have a H2 server that I start from console. The client from different machine accesses the server and calls a function alias (registered at the database). The problem is, this function is called more than a million times. So, in this case, the connection timesout but then I solved it with changing the client connection string to have AUTORECONNECT=TRUE. This solves the problem but adds a reconnection time delay (which I want to avoid).

Is there any flag/command that we can use to specify with Server to dedicate X amount of connections?

Also, I looked into the possibility of starting the server from within Application. Like,

```
  JdbcConnectionPool cp = JdbcConnectionPool.create(
             "jdbc:h2:tcp://IPADDRESS:9092/~/test", "sa", "");

  cp.setMaxConnections(MAX_CONN_IN_POOL);

  // start the TCP Server
  Server server = Server.createTcpServer().start();

  Connection conn = cp.getConnection();
  Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
  stat.execute("SELECT myFunctionAlias(arg)");

  cp.dispose();
  server.stop();
```

The above sample code does start the server and will only run once. I want the server to be open and keep listening to clients, and serve them from the connection pool. Any pointers?

Comment: Three items here. 1st: Connection pools are on the client side. 2nd: you need an infinite loop to serve. 3rd: You do not need a 'server' per-se, your clients should use a TCP connection to the DB an use the AUTO_SERVER=TRUE parameter. Please refer to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should start the server in AUTO_SERVER mode, this way a leader election algorithm will elect a leader who will read the database file and open a TCP server for all other clients.
Thsi way the server will be really fast to read the file while other clients will be as fast as the network is.
This is transparent to the user as long as you use the same connection string.

```
    Connection connection;
    String dataBaseString = "jdbc:h2:/path/to/db/" + File.separator + "db;create=true;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE";
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        log.info("getConnection(), driver found");
    }
    catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        log.error("getConnection(), ClassNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        Main.quit();
    }
    try
    {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dataBaseString);
    }
```